# "Enter the following verification code in the application: xxxxx" appears, but I do not find this application

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have an application, and I have been trying to log in to LinkedIn for a few days to call some information like: name, profile photo.
But every time I log in, when I click to give the permissions to the App, the following message appears: Inserts the following verification code in the application: (code).
I do not know where this "Application" is, I have already searched in many places and did not find it, and because of that I can not log in.
Could someone help me solve this problem please